# Installing subversion debian jessie last version

Tags: svn, debian-jessie

I just installed the subversion package : aptitude install subversion.

My problem is this installs the version 1.8 which is not the last (1.9)...

Why ?

Thanks.

Comment: Well it's debian choice, it's a lot of software that are not up to date in distributions. It seems to be available in debian Stretch though https://packages.debian.org/stretch/subversion. But it's still in testing mode.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presumably you're installing from the **Jessie** Debian repositories.

Debian Jessie, being the latest **stable** release of Debian, only serves packages which it deems to be **stable**. You can read more about this [here](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianReleases).

Currently, **Debian Jessie (stable)** ships with *Subversion 1.8.10-6+deb8u1* whilst **Debian Stretch (testing)** ships with *Subversion 1.9.2-2*. Once the version available in Debian Stretch has been tested and is considered stable it will likely be added to the **Jessie (Backports)** repository where it can be installed from there.

You can see this [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=subversion).

Debian are tracking bugs with Subversion 1.9 [here](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?pkg=subversion;dist=unstable).

If you need to install version 1.9 on Debian Jessie then you will have to build it from source; you can find information about installing from source [here](https://subversion.apache.org/source-code.html).

Comment: Ok thank you, I didn't know subersion 1.9 wasn't stable for jessie.

Comment: @NicolasThery Subversion 1.9 will never be stable for Jessie. Jessie came with svn 1.8 and Debian will not upgrade a package's major version until the next release.